# Op-Amp: Suggest improvement to get the right dc bias at output

Tags: operational-amplifier

Compute the output of the below given circuit. Suggest improvement to get the right dc bias at output:

[image]

Comment: This is phrased a lot like a homework question ... what have you managed to do so far? Also, that schematic is practically unreadable

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the barely readable supply voltage is 3.6V

## part 1, looking at the existing circuit

Firsty lets assume an ideal op-amp with unlimited swing.

The inverting gain of the amplifier is 10, so that means the sinewave source contributes a +-1V signal to the output.

The non-inverting gain of the amcplier is 11 and we have a voltage divider at the input proving half the supply voltage. So this contributes 5.5 times the supply voltage to the output.

We add these together and we get an output that varies from 18.8V to 20.8V.

Getting back to a real op-amp this clearly can't work, the output will be stuck high.

## Part 2, changing the bias point

We haven't been told what the desired DC offset in the output is but it's reasonable to assume that it is half of the supply voltage. That means that at the noninverting input we want a voltage that is 1/22 of the supply voltage.

To make that voltage we need a pair of resistors one of which is 21 times larger than the other. For example we can use a 21K resistor and a 1K resistor.

So now our output voltage theoretically goes from 0.8V to 2.8V.

## part 3, validation

We now need to check out our op-amp.

Turns out the input common mode voltage range on the LM124 includes ground, so we have no problems there.

However the output voltage swing on the LM124 is a strange beast. At the low end it can swing basically all the way to ground but at the high end it's limited to about 1.5V below the suppply voltage.

## part 4, adjusting the bias point again

So it turns out to make best use of the LM124 we want a DC offset of not 1.8V but 1.05V. So at the + input we need (1.05/11)V . As a fraction of the supply voltage that is (1.05/11)/3.6 which wolfram alpha tells me is 7/264

So the resistors need a ratio of 7:257

We can't make this exactly with a pair of standard resistors but we can get pretty close. http://jansson.us/resistors.html finds 1.15K and 42.2K as the closest pair from E96

## Conclusion

We have improved the circuit significantly but it's still running pretty close to the limit and you will pay for that in signal quality. It may be worth considering moving to wider supply rails or an op-amp with rail to rail output.

Comment: Is it somewhat related to this article? http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf                          Not only changing the resistor values but changing the circuit as well.

Answer (score 0):

WIth an academic question like this .(lol)

It a single negative supply, one looks for midscale DC output and then input adjusts the V+in so suit that and ensure input is in the acceptable common mode input range.

Then solve for Vin+ from Av+ based on (1 + |Av-|) and Vin- offset, then compute R Ratio to obtain Vin+ from Vcc&Vee.

That's all.  With practice .. 1minute